# building effective mysql ajax search

Tags: php, ajax

i am currently working on a search engine for a small database but feel as if my approach to building it has been a bit bloated so far. does anyone have any suggestions on how i could streamline the ajax code? here is my ajax.php file....

```
<p><a href="#clients" class="form">Clients</a> &nbsp;
<a href="#files" class="form">Files</a> &nbsp;
<a href="#vehicles" class="form">Vehicles</a> &nbsp;
<a href="#comments" class="form">Comments</a> &nbsp;
<a href="#solicitors" class="form">Solicitors</a> &nbsp;</p>

<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>






<!--- CLIENTS ---->

<p style='font-size: 16px;'><b><a name="clients">Clients</a></b></p>

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php');
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE clientName LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY clientName ASC");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg=$row['clientName'];
$bold_word='<b>'.$search_word.'</b>';
$final_msg = str_ireplace($search_word, $bold_word, $msg);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a class='box' href='viewclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['address']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='manageclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='printclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/print.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deleteclient.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?></p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (road traffic accident)<BR>
</p>";
}
}
?>

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php');
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word6=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql6=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_personalinjury WHERE clientName LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY clientName ASC");
$count6=mysql_num_rows($sql6);
if($count6 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql6))
{
$msg6=$row['clientName'];
$bold_word6='<b>'.$search_word6.'</b>';
$final_msg6 = str_ireplace($search_word6, $bold_word6, $msg6);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a class='box' href='viewclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg6."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['address']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='manageclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='printclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/print.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deleteclient2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?></p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (personal injury)<BR>
</p>";
}
}
?>

<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>






<!--- FILES ---->

<p style='font-size: 16px;'><b><a name="files">Files</a></b></p>

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php');        
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word2=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_accidentfiles WHERE name LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY name ASC");
$count2=mysql_num_rows($sql2);
if($count2 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
$msg2=$row['name'];
$bold_word2='<b>'.$search_word2.'</b>';
$final_msg2 = str_ireplace($search_word2, $bold_word2, $msg2);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a class='box' href='viewfile.php?id=".$row['id']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg2."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['size']."K&nbsp;".$row['type']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='downloadfile.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/download.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewfile.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletefile.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (road traffic accident)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php');        
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word7=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql7=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_personalinjuryfiles WHERE name LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY name ASC");
$count7=mysql_num_rows($sql7);
if($count7 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql7))
{
$msg7=$row['name'];
$bold_word7='<b>'.$search_word7.'</b>';
$final_msg7 = str_ireplace($search_word7, $bold_word7, $msg7);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a class='box' href='viewfile3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg7."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['size']."K&nbsp;".$row['type']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='downloadfile3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/download.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewfile3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletefile3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (personal injury)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word3=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_vehiclefiles WHERE name LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY name ASC");
$count3=mysql_num_rows($sql3);
if($count3 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
{
$msg3=$row['name'];
$bold_word3 ='<b>'.$search_word3.'</b>';
$final_msg3 = str_ireplace($search_word3, $bold_word3, $msg3);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a class='box' href='viewfile2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg2."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['size']."K&nbsp;".$row['type']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='downloadfile2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/download.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewfile2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletefile2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (vehicle)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>

<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>

<p style='font-size: 16px;'><b><a name="vehicles">Vehicles</a></b></p>








<!--- VEHICLES ---->

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php'); 

if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word6=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql6=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_vehicles WHERE vehicleMake LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY vehicleMake DESC");
$count6=mysql_num_rows($sql6);
if($count6 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql6))
{
$msg6=$row['vehicleMake']."&nbsp;".$row['vehicleModel'];
$bold_word6='<b>'.$search_word6.'</b>';
$final_msg6 = str_ireplace($search_word6, $bold_word6, $msg6);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<span style='font-size: 12px;'><a class='box' href='viewvehicle.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$final_msg6."</a></span><BR>
<a href='managevehicle.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='viewvehicle.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editvehicle.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletevehicle.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results<BR></p>";
}
}
?>

<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>

<p style='font-size: 16px;'><b><a name="comments">Comments</a></b></p>








<!--- COMMENTS ---->

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php');

function do_TrimString($string, $MaxSTRLEN = null) {
   if ($MaxSTRLEN == null) { global $MaxSTRLEN; }
   if (strlen($string) > $MaxSTRLEN) {
      $string = substr($string, 0, $MaxSTRLEN);
      $end = strrpos($string, ' ');
      if ($end === false) {
         $end = $MaxSTRLEN;
         }
      $string = substr($string, 0, $end) . '...';
      }
   return $string;
   }

if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word4=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE comment LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY comment ASC");
$count4=mysql_num_rows($sql4);
if($count4 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql4))
{
$msg4=$row['comment'];
$bold_word4='<b>'.$search_word4.'</b>';
$final_msg4 = str_ireplace($search_word4, $bold_word4, $msg4);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a href='viewcomment.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='box'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".do_TrimString($final_msg4, 40)."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['date']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='viewcomment.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='manageclient.php?id=".$row['client_id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editcomment.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletecomment.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (road traffic accident)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word4=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_comment3 WHERE comment LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY comment ASC");
$count4=mysql_num_rows($sql4);
if($count4 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql4))
{
$msg4=$row['comment'];
$bold_word4='<b>'.$search_word4.'</b>';
$final_msg4 = str_ireplace($search_word4, $bold_word4, $msg4);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a href='editcomment3.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='box'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".do_TrimString($final_msg4, 40)."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['date']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='manageclient2.php?id=".$row['client_id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editcomment3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletecomment3.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (personal injury)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word4=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql4=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_comment2 WHERE comment LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY comment ASC");
$count4=mysql_num_rows($sql4);
if($count4 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql4))
{
$msg4=$row['comment'];
$bold_word4='<b>'.$search_word4.'</b>';
$final_msg4 = str_ireplace($search_word4, $bold_word4, $msg4);
?>
<p><?php echo "
<a href='editcomment2.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='box'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".do_TrimString($final_msg4, 40)."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['date']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='managevehicle.php?id=".$row['veh_id']."'><img src='resources/manage.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='editcomment2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/edit.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletecomment2.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<BR>"; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results (vehicle)<BR></p>";
}
}
?>
<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>










<p style='font-size: 16px;'><b><a name="solicitors">Solicitors</a></b></p>

<!--- 5) tbl_solicitors search ---->

<?php require_once('Connections/speedycms.php'); 

if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word5=$_GET['search_word'];
$sql5=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_solicitors WHERE solicitorName LIKE '%$search_word%' ORDER BY solicitorName ASC");
$count5=mysql_num_rows($sql5);
if($count5 > 0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql5))
{
$msg5=$row['solicitorName'];
$bold_word5='<b>'.$search_word5.'</b>';
$final_msg5 = str_ireplace($search_word5, $bold_word5, $msg5);
?>
<p><?php 
if($row['solicitorName']=='None')
{
echo "<p>No results<BR></p>";   
}
else
echo "
<a class='box' href='viewsolicitor.php?id=".$row['solicitorName']."'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$final_msg5."</span><BR>
<span style='font-size: 10px;'>".$row['solicitorDetail']."</span></a><BR>
<a href='viewsolicitor.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/view.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;
<a href='deletesolicitor.php?id=".$row['id']."'><img src='resources/no.png' border='0'></a>&nbsp;<BR>
"; 
?>
</p>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo "<p>No results<BR></p>";
}
}
?>

<hr width='75%' size='1' color='#F5F5F5' align='left'/>
```

thanking you in advance

Comment: Please consider indenting logical blocks of code (in it's current form I find this plain unreadable)...

Comment: ok will do... is this better?

Comment: You haven't indented anything, except for that one function in the middle. Proper indentation will serve you well throughout your career, and prevent people from despising your code BEFORE they read it.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could describe just what it is about your current approach you don't like? I suspect no one has bothered to answer yet because they're not sure what it is you're getting at. There are obviously many approaches one could use, and while I could certainly make suggestions, there's no guarantee the time I'd invest to do so would be helpful in answering your fundamental question, whatever that is, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides making sure your code is properly indented ;) I'd consider separating out your presentation (HTML) and business logic better.

I'm not talking about a full on template system or anything like that, but if you could at least collect your processing code (queries, etc) at the top of the file and move all the presentation code to the bottom, I think you'll get a better grasp on where you're actually at so far, and what you can do to improve it.